# C++ overflow : not enough SRAM to hold the code

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile a C++ code, in this code I am defining two large arrays of 405 elements each.

```
double a [405] = {...};
double b [405] = {...};
```

Then I convert these into vectors using this function:

```
std::vector<double> ArrayToVector(double* arr, size_t arr_len) {
return std::vector<double>(arr, arr + arr_len);
}
```

Then I do the conversion:

```
std::vector<double> coefs_vec= ArrayToVector(a,405);
std::vector<double> ft_vec= ArrayToVector(b,405);
```

And here were the overflow occurs and I get those errors:

```
 error: sram_out/sram.elf section `.text' will not fit in region `int_main'
 error: region `int_main' overflowed by 35816 bytes
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried using dynamic memory for some previous used variables but the problem is mainly caused by this big arrays. Is there a way I can solve this problem? Maybe a better way to define those arrays with less memory usage.

Comment: Does [Region ram overflowed and section .text will not fit region ram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044660/7582247) help?

Comment: Why not do `std::vector<double> coefs_vec{ ... };` directly? Why do you need `a`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I get this error ´error: in C++98 'features_vec' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'´´ and ´error: could not convert  from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<float>'´

Comment: Do you need to use C++98? It's over 2 decades old and the language has changed a lot since then. What compiler and compiler version are you using?