# section .data will not fit in region 'dff' error

Tags: c, gcc, ram, riscv

I was trying to run some c program on a RISCV processor and I got this:

```
/foss/tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain-rv32i/217e7f3debe424d61374d31e33a091a630535937/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: test_la.elf section `.data' will not fit in region `dff'
/foss/tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain-rv32i/217e7f3debe424d61374d31e33a091a630535937/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: region `dff' overflowed by 1624 bytes
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

According to a comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041390/region-ram-overflowed-and-section-text-will-not-fit-region-ram) thread, it might be caused by declaring some large global arrays. And it is true for me, I have these globally (outside the main function):

```
int sig_A [Bits] = { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1};

int sig_B [Bits] = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

int sig_C [Bits] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0};

int data_i [Bits] = { 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 0, 0};
```

I need these data to be send from the RISCV to some digital circuit. How can I make this happen (if there is a way). Thank you.

**linker file**

```
/* Copyright lowRISC contributors.
   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0, see LICENSE for details.
   SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 */

INCLUDE ../generated/output_format.ld

OUTPUT_ARCH(riscv)

/*******
MEMORY
{

   Change this if you'd like different sizes. Arty A7-100(35) has a maximum of 607.5KB(225KB)
   BRAM space. Configuration below is for maximum BRAM capacity with Artya A7-35 while letting
   CoreMark run (.vmem of 152.8KB).
    ram         : ORIGIN = 0x00100000, LENGTH = 0x30000 * 192 kB *
    stack       : ORIGIN = 0x00130000, LENGTH = 0x8000  * 32 kB *
}
**********/

_entry_point = _vectors_start + 0x80;
ENTRY(_entry_point)

/* The tohost address is used by Spike for a magic "stop me now" message. This
   is set to equal SIM_CTRL_CTRL (see simple_system_regs.h), which has that
   effect in simple_system simulations. Note that it must be 8-byte aligned.

   We don't read data back from Spike, so fromhost is set to some dummy value:
   we place it just above the top of the stack.
 */
tohost   = 0x20008;
fromhost = _stack_start + 0x10;

SECTIONS
{
    .vectors :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _vectors_start = .;
        KEEP(*(.vectors))
        _vectors_end = .;
    } > flash

    .text : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.text)
        *(.text.*)
    }  > flash

    .rodata : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* Small RO data before large RO data */
        *(.srodata)
        *(.srodata.*)
        *(.rodata);
        *(.rodata.*)
    } > flash

    .data : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* Small data before large data */
        *(.sdata)
        *(.sdata.*)
        *(.data);
        *(.data.*)
    } > dff AT > flash

    .bss :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _bss_start = .;
        /* Small BSS before large BSS */
        *(.sbss)
        *(.sbss.*)
        *(.bss)
        *(.bss.*)
        *(COMMON)
        _bss_end = .;
    } > dff

}

PROVIDE(_stack_start = ORIGIN(sram) + LENGTH(sram));
```

Comment: You probably need to provide more info on your sizes of regions, RAM, sections, ... and other details of your linker setup.

Comment: Is that real data or close to real data? Are all values withing 1 digit range? Do they need sent identically to the way thea are stored in memory? You might reduce size by using `uint8_t` instead of `int` for your arrays and only convert to `int` before sending.

Comment: What is the value of `Bits`?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I changed the int to uint8_t and the error disappeared for now @Gerhardh -- yes these are the exact same data I want to send.

Comment: A further reduction can be had if `Bits` is larger than the number of elements/commas in your declarations. Also, if the range of the values is (e.g.) `0-3`, you can pack them into 3 bits and extract them with some bit shifting/masking

Comment: Are the arrays unchanged during the runtime? If you make such arrays `const`, they do not fill up your precious RAM. If your linker script is well-designed, they are allocated to ROM (flash, whatever).

Comment: @thebusybee thanks. yes. they will be fixed

Comment: @CraigEstey thanks for your suggestion, the Bits value is 164 (is the same number of elements)

Comment: @Yunnosch  I'm not very familiar with the linker thing, but I'm interested to learn about it. I added its contents to my question, thanks

Comment: Seems like you're tight on RAM/memory. Changing `int` to `uint8_t` reduces the total from 2624 bytes to 656 bytes. But, 2624 isn't all that much, so what make/model of  processor/SDK board do you have? And how much memory (e.g. ram, rom, cache, etc.)? I'd expect this small memory size on (e.g.) a Microchip PIC18 which only has a KB or so, but, a RISCV impl. should have [significantly] more. Is the DTB (device tree blob) correct for your system? Look for `.dts/.dti/.dtb` files. If you're truly limited to a few KB, with the 3 bit trick, the memory reduces to ~246 bytes.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thank you for the info. IDK if you already know about this but I am using [link](https://github.com/efabless/caravel) and I'm just simulating (no boards at the moment)

Comment: @CraigEstey could you please point me to a link to understand the linker script myself?

Answer (score 1):

> could you please point me to a link to understand the linker script myself? –
> temp1445

I did a web search on `"linker script" documentation` and got (amongst 1.2M): https://wiki.osdev.org/Linker_Scripts

I downloaded the repo you linked to [all 14 GB of it ;-)]. In the repo, we have a few files:

```
./verilog/dv/caravel/sections.lds
./verilog/dv/caravel/mgmt_soc/irq/sections.lds
```

They are similar except for the origin address of `RAM`. Here is a snippet of the first:

```
MEMORY {
    FLASH (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x400000    /* 4MB */
    RAM(xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x0400      /* 256 words (1 KB) */
}
```

This means that you *only* have **1 KB** of ram!

But, your example refers to `dff`. There is a python script that refers to a linker script by that name, but it must be [auto-]generated as there is no `dff.lds` in the tree.

---

AFAICT, `caravel` is a *gate* level verilog/VHDL design for a riscv FPGA or ASIC implementation.

I *have* done [linux] S/W kernel porting to a new ASIC CPU design [20 years ago], using a *gate* level simulator.

But, this can be *very* slow.

For example, during boot, linux would go into a spin loop to calculate CPU speed (i.e. BogoMIPS). This test, on real H/W takes a small fraction of a second (e.g. 1ms). On the simulator, it took one full day.

So, I replaced that loop with a NOP, and hardwired the frequency (using (e.g.)):

```
#ifdef _USE_GATE_SIMULATOR_
bogoMIPS = 200;
#else
while (...) {
}
bogoMIPS = ...;
#endif
```

Then, we had to develop S/W device drivers for the [proposed] H/W. The verilog code for some of the H/W wasn't complete.

But, we did have functional specs for the H/W.

Our solution was to do most of the S/W development on:

1. A *functional* emulator (similar to `qemu`) to which we added emulation of the H/W devices.
2. Userspace code, run on the development machine (e.g. x86 PC) that ran x86 code and had a library that allowed us to make calls into the H/W emulation functions.
3. A real H/W SDK board that had similar H/W
4. The gate level simulator

We configured the S/W to be able to work in any of these environments with conditional compilation.

We did most of the S/W development work using (2) and (1). When we were 99.44% sure that there were no *software* bugs (e.g. UB, etc.), only then would we do a full verification using (3).

That way, we didn't burn *hours* of simulator time to find a [trivial] S/W bug that was found in 5 seconds on the SDK board or emulator.

This also allowed the programmers to be able to debug the S/W independently of the H/W designers verilog code [which often had *more* bugs than the S/W did].

---

You didn't specify what your primary goal was, but I'd highly recommend a build environment like that.

If you're just wanting to experiment with the riscv architecture at the assembly level, then I'd use `qemu` or equivalent.

If you're trying to write S/W to drive current/proposed H/W devices, I'd still recommend a similar strategy to what we had.

Comment: Valuable stuff. Thank you very much for sharing. Glad you looked through caravel :) 
It is for asic design and it has a user space to accommodate our design and we use the riscv (core management wrapper) to configure the gpio pads on the padframe and also to use it as input/output source/sink (which I intend to do)

Answer (score 1):

Your program defines some big arrays, which are bigger than the available RAM. The error message says (cut the prefix with the linker's path):

```
test_la.elf section `.data' will not fit in region `dff'
region `dff' overflowed by 1624 bytes
```

The section `.data` collects all writable static<sup>*</sup> variables, and this includes the arrays. Since this section is allocated in the region `dff`, it will overflow.

Now you have at least two options.

###### 1. Reduce the size of the arrays

You say in a comment that all values in the arrays are as small as shown, in the range 0 to 6. The element data type is `int`, which seems to have a size of 4 bytes. This is a lot for storing small values.

You can invent some way to pack only needed bits into available space, but this needs some unpacking code at run time, depending on the purpose of the values.

A simpler way is to use the smallest possible and appropriate data type, in your case `uint8_t`. You did this as you confirm in a comment, and it solved the issue for the moment.

However, as soon as you add more variables to your program, the same issue will rise again. Therefore, I suggest to use the second option.

Depending on the usage of the values, you can additionally combine both options, minimizing the footprint of the arrays in ROM, too.

###### 2. Move the arrays to ROM

As you confirm in a comment, your program only reads the values of these arrays, their contents are fixed.

Add the modifier `const` to them. This will put them into the section `.rodata`, which means "read-only data". As this section is allocated in the region `flash`, it will not fill up your scarce RAM.

*Note: Be aware that some processors might need special instructions to read data from ROM. Depending on the necessity and the cleverness of the compiler, this might need changes to your code, or not. Just saying.*

Anyway, you should always use modifiers to show such characteristics. Beginner's courses rarely get to this, and on PCs they get away without. But in the embedded world, always modify read-only variables with `const`.

---

Here is a hint to check the memory usage: Let the linker generate a map file. For GNU based tool chains, look up [the option `-Map`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.39/ld/Options.html). For example, you can add `-Wl,-Map=output.map` to the command line, if you run the linker via the frontend "gcc".

---

*) Global variables are also static.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Great information. Things are clearer now. Sorry, where to look up for the -Map option?

Comment: See my edit, it adds a link. A web search on "gnu linker map" revealed it. If you think this answers your question, please mark it as accepted.